# How to reuse reviewed documents in further translations?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, microsoft-translator

Our instruction manual is in markdown format. We improve the manual daily or weekly and then we would like to translate to other languages. Until now, this process is manual and we use TRADOS (a assisted translation software)

We are studying to improve the process. What we want to do is to translate it using Microsoft translator and then a human reviewer do the fine tune. The problem is how we can reuse the corrected document in Microsoft Translator for the next translation.

Many times we only change 2 or 3 words of a topic and then the translator would create a complete new translation, doing the reviewer work very tedious if the translation is not accurate.

I know that we can train the model, but I think that there is not a 100% of probabilities that the translator uses the review. Also, it seems very time consuming to maintain the distortionary after reviewing the document.

I was wondering if somebody has solved this kind a problem.

Answer (score 0):

We can automate the translation of the document using Microsoft Flow. In Microsoft flow we can use the SharePoint service to store the file which we need to translate and then we can create a flow of operation.

1. Need to create a folder in SharePoint and mention the site address
2. Mention the folder name and to which language you need to translate it when the file is available in the SharePoint folder
3. Give the destination folder. Again, it can be a SharePoint folder.

Note: Can't assure that the meaning after translation will be the same as the original statement.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a translation memory system (TMS). A TMS will store your human edits to documents and reapply them to future translations of documents where a paragraph is repeated. A TMS will also help your human translator find close matches of a new segment with a previously translated one, highlighting the change the human will have to perform.
Most TMSes integrate machine translation systems like Microsoft Translator and others as a suggestion to the human editor, who can then approve or edit the suggestion.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_memory

When selecting a TMS here are some features to consider:

- Integration with the content management system (CMS) your business uses for storing, maintaining and publishing documents
- Collaboration: Multiple people working on a shared set of documents
- Workflow management: Initiate a translation job, track the progress of it, and execute payments to the collaborating humans
- Ease of use and translator acceptance of the human-facing CAT component of the TMS
- Pretranslate with your favorite machine translation system from inside the TMS

Once you have collected a significant amount of domain-specific human translations, you can train a custom translation system directly from the content of your TMS, tuning future machine translations in the direction of the terminology and style that are exemplified by your human translations.

Answer (score 0):

You said you already use Trados.  So why don't you create a Translation Memory in Trados, and save your corrected work to that Translation Memory.  Then the next time you create your project in Trados, presumably also using the MS Translator plugin that is [freely available from the RWS AppStore](https://appstore.rws.com/plugin/19/) you will pre-translate using your translation memory AND MS Translator.  Any work you translated before and is in your translation memory will be used in preference to the machine translation result.
If you have the professional version of Trados you can also use Perfect Match.  If you do this then when you receive your updated document with only a few words to change you match it against the bilingual file from your previous translation.  Everything that remains the same receives a Perfect Match status and is optionally locked making it simple to identify what needs to be changed by the translator.